# Pgsql query help needed with two tables with foreign key

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables: **mst_general_age_range** and **data_016_genderwise_headofhouse**, in the data_016_genderwise_headofhouse table there is a foreign key of mst_general_age_range called age_range_id:

[image: two datatables]

I need this kind of report to be generated:

[image: needed snap]
please help me with query, its postgresql database.

Comment: please ignore the total column after gender

Comment: `SELECT t2.name_en, sum(t1.total), sum(t1.male),sum(t1.female)  

FROM
    data_016_genderwise_headofhouse t1
left join mst_general_age_range t2 
on t2.id = t1.age_range_id
where t1.local_level_id=1
group by t2.name_en
order by t2.name_en;`

Comment: What you want is "cross tabulation" or "pivot"

Comment: yes, but i am not able to do it, please can you provide me the real query of this one